# Spree with deface - Use deface to replace contents of block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I have an erb block:

```
 <% content_for :sidebar do %>
 <% if defined? @products && defined? @taxon %>
   <%= render :partial => "spree/shared/filters" %>
     <% elsif defined? @taxonomies %>
   <%= render :partial => "spree/shared/taxonomies" %>
     <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

I want to put different contents inside the content_for block so I tried defacing it like so:

```
<!-- replace_contents "erb[silent]:contains('content_for :sidebar')" -->
<%= render partial: "test" %>
```

This raises an error:

> syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting keyword_end

Defacing a ruby block is something I never tried before.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of `content_for` in -

```
<!-- replace_contents "erb[silent]:contains('content_for :sidebar')" -->
```

`content_for` is an helper method in rails which stores a block of markup inside `do.....end` for later use.

and `erb[silent]:contains()` selector in deface works on ruby/rails code.

So when you are writing `'content_for :sidebar'` inside selector it finds `do...end` missing and generates error of `expecting keyword_end`

For example this code will not raise any error -

```
<!-- replace_contents "erb[silent]:contains('if @product.sold?')" -->
```

because `if @product.sold?` is a valid ruby/rails code.

Comment: Thank you! I did just that. I ended up with the following code:    <!-- replace_contents "erb[silent]:contains('if defined? @products && defined? @taxon')" 
  closing_selector "erb[silent]:contains('end')" -->